# Why do we pronounce "slurp" with ə, but "slump" with ʌ?

Tags: pronunciation, american-english, canadian-english

Why do we pronounce slurp as [/sləːp/](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/slurp?q=slurp) or /slɜ:p/ (BrE) or /slɝ:p/ (AmE) (Cambridge Dictionary of Pronunciation), but *slump* as [/slʌmp/](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/slump?q=slump)?

Is it because of the presence of R?

Comment: It might be. I'm no expert on these things, but there are several other words I can think of off the top of my head that fit this pattern: *lump*, *lumbar* are both pronounced like *slump*. *lurch*, *church* are both pronounced like *slurp*. I suppose it could be a coincidence, but just throwing that out there :)

Comment: Hmm, although it just occurred to me, the general idea is that "what" questions belong on ELL and "why" questions on ELU. I had this thought based on your edit, which added the last sentence to your question (re: etymology etc.). I'll wait and see if anyone else agrees with me, though, or perhaps get the opinion of an ELU mod if one is around :)

Comment: I notice that when you try to pronounce either word the other way round, it's difficult (for an AE speaker) to do!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vowels with /r/ following them are treated differently in English.

Most Americans never put an /r/ after an /ʌ/.  Most English people don't put an /r/ after an /ʌ/ when they're in the same syllable (in fact, many of them don't put an /r/ after *any* vowel in the same syllable). In these cases, a word which historically should have been pronounced /ʌr/ is instead pronounced with /ɝ:/ or /ɜ:/.  In Scotland and Ireland, they [can and do](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_English#Phonology) pronounce /ʌr/, although not being Scottish I have no idea which vowel they use for slurp.

The history of the pronunciation of 'r' after a vowel in English is quite complicated, and when learning English you just have to learn that curd, herd, bird, all rhyme (except in Scotland and Ireland).

Comment: "current" and possible "currency" [sounds](http://www.forvo.com/word/current/#en) and are [shown](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/current?q=current) with an /\ in British English but not in AmE.

Comment: But as my tags suggest, I was more interested on North-American pronunciation

Comment: @Theta30: in British English, "current", "currency", "hurry", and similar words can be pronounced with /ʌr/ because the /ʌr/ is immediately followed by a vowel, so the 'r' gets shifted to be pronounced as the first sound of the next syllable. I don't believe you will find /ʌrC/ in standard British English, with 'C' representing a consonant.